# Vagrant not working - timeout while waiting for the machine to boot

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant-windows

I have installed the latest versions of `Virtualbox v.5.2.6` and `Vagrant v.2.0.1` on the windows machine with the `Intel-Core-i5-4210U-Processor @1.70Ghz 2.40Ghz`. I have added the homestead box by running the command:

```
 vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

But, on running the `vagrant up` it runs fine until this point:

> Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
>   Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within the
>   configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
>
> If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that Vagrant
>   had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors are
>   usually good hints as to what may be wrong.
>
> If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
>   working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
>   problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes. Verify
>   that authentication configurations are also setup properly, as well.
>
> If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
>   the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

On running the `vagrant ssh-config` I get:

```
Host homestead-7
HostName 127.0.0.1
User vagrant
Port 2222
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
StrictHostKeyChecking no
PasswordAuthentication no
IdentityFile C:/Users/MyUser/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
IdentitiesOnly yes
LogLevel FATAL
ForwardAgent yes
```

I have looked around and tried out different things, among others, to uninstall and install again both `vagrant` and `virtualbox`, but couldn't find any solution. How can I get this working?